# Strobiloid representation

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, density-function

I am working with household income and I would like to replicate the following strobiloids generated by Chauvel (2013): 
[image]

For what I understand here and from his explanation of the graph, he plots the density function of the normalized income on the x-axis and the medianization of the income on the vertical one. What I was wondering is how to combine a univariate graph (like the density) with another variable that is the medianization of income? 
He mentions the ABG method for smoothing the empirical quantile distribution, but also acknowledges that the Kernel smoothing may generate the same results. But still I cannot understand the graphical representation. 
Any suggestion/idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "medianization of income"?

Comment: Looking at the graph, I suppose that it's the ratio between the income and the median of the distribution, so that you have 1 when income equals the median, 2 when it's 2 times the median and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to understand this graphical representation method better.

I'm not familiar with the term 'strobiloid', but these plots are also called [split violin plots](https://mbjoseph.github.io/posts/2018-12-23-split-violin-plots/), or sometimes semi-violin plots. Within a panel, each half represents a kernel density plot turned on its side. If you are not familiar with kernel density plots, think of them as smoothed versions of histograms.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware about split violin plots in R, I was just using geom_violin within the ggplot2 package. Thank you!

Comment: @LucaGiangregorio Does this answer your question? I wasn't completely sure if this was what you were trying to understand

Comment: I think so, I am going to try this plot. But I suppose that using the years as grouping, I can plot the kernel of normalized income for a given year on the left side of the panel and the kernel of another year on the right one and this would be perfect